# How do I get CURRENT_DATE in MSSQL?

Tags: java, date

I am using jpa 3.o with Hibernate. I have one named query:

```
SELECT COUNT(wt.id) FROM WPSTransaction wt WHERE wt.createdDate>= CURRENT_DATE
```

WPSTransaction is my entity class and createdDate is one of the columns in my class.

It's working fine in the Mysql Database. However, I'm moving to SQL Server 2012 and SQL server doesn't seem to compile the `CURRENT_DATE` value. I've tried `GETNOW()` and `NOW()` methods as well as `current_date()` method and `CURRENT_TIMESTAMP` without any luck.

Comment: Can you clarify what "without any luck means"?

Answer (score 2):

MS SQL Server [fails to conform to the standard](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh501296%28v=sql.105%29.aspx) here - it does not provide a `current_date` keyword.

You must instead use the SQL-server specific `GETDATE()` function, as the document linked shows.

Because `current_date` is a keyword in the spec, you can't just create a user-defined `current_date()` function in MS SQL and expect it to work the same. So unfortunately you're stuck with database-specific code here.

Comment: `current_timestamp()` is also available and a little closer to standard

Answer (score 1):

The function to return the current date in SQL Server is `GETDATE()`, so your query should read

```
SELECT COUNT(wt.id) 
FROM WPSTransaction wt 
WHERE wt.createdDate >= GETDATE()
```

Comment: i already used GETDATE() method.. but it doesnt give the count.

Comment: GETDATE() returns date *and* time, so this query is for rows created in the future: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms188383.aspx

Answer (score 1):

How about:

```
Query q = entityManager.createQuery("SELECT COUNT(wt.id) FROM WPSTransaction wt WHERE wt.createdDate>= :d");
q.setParam("d", new Date());
```

No database specific code needed.